# I was trying to select only the positions that are active, the error says ">"cannot apply to the operands of bool, how can i resolve this

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I was trying to select only the positions that are active, the error says ">"cannot apply to the operands of bool, how can i resolve this

```cs
var post = await _dm.Positions
    .Where(w => w.StoreId == storeid && w.Name == name && w.ID != postid && 
        w.Active > 0)
    .Select(s => new DtoPosition(s))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Well presumably `w.Active` is a `bool`, and you can't compare a `bool` with an integer. Perhaps you just meant `w.Active`?

Comment: Or in other words: if `w.Active` is a `bool`, then w.Active itself can be `true` or `false`. And the expression `w.Active==true` can be `true` or `false` too

Comment: Can you tell me what `true > 0` and `false > 0` mean to you?